# Attach FileAttachment to message.Attachments in c# EWS

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices, attachment

I am trying to add a `FileAttachment` to a message. Unfortunately `message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment()` asks for a path, which I don't have. I have the `FileAttachment` straight from another mail.

Here I get the attachment:

```
EmailMessage oldEmailMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(service, olderSoxMail.Id);
// load attachments
FileAttachment fileAttachment = newEmailMessage.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;
fileAttachment.Load();
```

Here I try to attach the attachment to a mail

```
public static void ComposeEmail(string recipient, string subject, string body, FileAttachment[] attachment = null)
{
    var map = new Dictionary<char, string>() {
        { 'ä', "ae" },
        { 'ö', "oe" },
        { 'ü', "ue" },
        { 'Ä', "Ae" },
        { 'Ö', "Oe" },
        { 'Ü', "Ue" },
        { 'ß', "ss" }
    };
    recipient = recipient.Aggregate(
      new StringBuilder(),
      (sb, c) =>
      {
          string r;
          if (map.TryGetValue(c, out r))
              return sb.Append(r);
          else
              return sb.Append(c);
      }).ToString();

    EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.Body = body;
    message.ToRecipients.Add(recipient);

    foreach (FileAttachment attach in attachment)
    {
        // COMPILER ERROR HERE: Cannot Convert from FileAttachment to Path (string)
        message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(attach);
        // END ERROR
    }

    message.SendAndSaveCopy();
}
```

Do you know how I can add the `FileAttachment`?

Comment: "...error here..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: Visual studio tells me the path to the attachment file is required. I cannot even compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your fileattachments that you are receiving exist on the Exchange server. You can download those attachments and store the path and attach those paths to your new email.

A better solution is reading the attachments as streams and attach them directly to the mail without saving them to disk first.

```
foreach (var fileAttachment in fileAttachments)
{
    var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(fileAttachment.Content);
    message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(fileAttachment.Name, stream);
}
```